# Scalatra: Generate reverse route from another Servlet

Tags: scala, routes, scalatra

### Use-case

I'm writing a simple REST api to evaluate Scalatra for my needs. I have two controllers (servlets?), mounted to `/items/*` and `/categories/*` in `ScalatraBootstrap`. I want a `GET` request to `/items/1` to return something like this:

```
{
   "name": "item1",
   "category": {
     "url": "/categories/1"
   }
}
```

I can't find a way to generate `/categories/1`. The last section in http://www.scalatra.org/2.2/guides/http/reverse-routes.html looks like what I need, except it doesn't describe a way to use the functionality across servlets.

### What I tried

- Created a companion object for the servlet responsible for `/categories`, and tried to use the `Route` from there. I got an exception with the message `requirement failed: routeBasePath requires the servlet to be initialized`. This leads me to believe that there's some conceptual limitation that prevents this usage, but then the documentation says that `ScalateUrlGeneratorSupport` does even more than this. I'm confused.
- Copy-pasted the trait removed in https://github.com/ornicar/scalatra/commit/625f8a287d466122d8a0774b71188a62ec07ecb6, mixed it into the `items` servlet, tried to get the route based on the route name. Resulting exception: `scala.runtime.BoxedUnit cannot be cast to org.scalatra.Route`

To make the question explicit: is there a way to use a named `Route` from one servlet to generate a URL in another servlet?

(Please feel free to correct my terminology, I'm coming pretty fresh from Python-land)

Comment: Nope, I ended up manually generating the URL strings.

Comment: Unfortunate. Thanks for the response!